# Must my android app be published on market to earn Ad revenue from AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I have written my first android app and have successfully included the AdMob ads into the app.
Must I publish the app via Market (Google Play) in order to start earning revenue?

Additionally I understand that while in Development, we need to put in the Test Device to indicate that the Ad is still in test mode. When I publish the app for real, all I have to do is remove the testDevice from my code right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must I publish the app via Market (Google Play) in order to start earning revenue?

You need to publish your app and make it available for others to download and install it so that when they use the app, the ad requests are served. Only when the users click your ads will you be generating revenue.

If your question was whether it is mandatory that you have to publish the app **only** on Google Play store to earn revenue, I think it is not necessary.

IIRC, there is no mention on [Publisher guidelines and policies](https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307237&topic=1307235&parent=1307209&rd=1) that prevents a publisher from publishing the app on alternative Android markets. You should consult a legal adviser if you need more clarity on the [ToS](http://www.admob.com/home/terms).

> Additionally I understand that while in Development, we need to put in the Test Device to indicate that the Ad is still in test mode. When I publish the app for real, all I have to do is remove the testDevice from my code right?

You can leave the test device id so as to prevent clicking the ads from your test device.

Comment: you don't remove the test device from the code. the test device is the identifier of your own telephone, so that you will never click on your own ads accidentally. keep it in your code at all time imo.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you set testmode = false in client end or check disable all test mode in admob site and you start earning...